Ip white list in wordpress using traefik
I have a wordpress dockerized and i'm trying to block the access for /wp-login.php from outside the vpn. The problem is when i try to do that i block the whole page. Someone knows how to do that?
this is a part of the yml
version: '3.7'
services:
traefik:
  image: traefik:v2.5
configs:
  - source: traefik_traefik_tls_config
    target: /etc/traefik/tls.toml
  - source: traefik_security
    target: /etc/traefik/security.toml   
command:
  - "--api.insecure=true"
  - "--providers.docker=true"
  - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
  - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
  - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
  - "--providers.file=true"
  - "--providers.file.directory=/etc/traefik"  

labels:
  - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=host(`wp-test.com`)" 
  - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=web"
  - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https@docker"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https" 

ports:
  - "80:80"
  - "443:443"
  - "8080:8080"
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

wordpress:
image: wordpress:latest
restart: always
environment:
  - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=fede
  - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=fede
  - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=fede
  - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=fede
labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress.tls=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress.rule=Host(`wp-test.com`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress.entrypoints=web,websecure"
  - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress-admin.rule=Host(`wp-test.com`) && PathPrefix(`/wp-login.php`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress-admin.entrypoints=web,websecure"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.wordpress-admin-ipwhitelist.ipwhitelist.sourceRange=10.180.10.0/16"
  - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress-admin.middlewares=wordpress-admin-ipwhitelist"
  - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress.middlewares=redirect-to-https@docker" 
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"

